# Is it absolutely not possible to use Google maps in iOS 6..?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios5, ios6, ios6-maps

I want to know if is it not at all possible to use Google maps on iOS 6 ?

I had one App prepared and now when I am using it iOS 6, It automatically takes Apple maps !

Since I dont want to use Apple maps, So I want to know if any how,Is it possible to use Google maps on 
iOS 6 !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still google maps, but not on mapkit. The google maps has a very useful API you can use to generate the maps. You won't be able to use MKMapKit thou, but you can use google's static maps API to show the map content.

Edit: here's a new open source project with google maps tile [Link](https://github.com/mladjan/GoogleMapsOverlayiOS) and here is a link for the alternative, official,  bing maps toolkit [Link](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk.aspx)

Comment: Also what i want to ask is, Will Apple approve the App with Google API..?

Comment: Yes. You can also use the Bing maps toolkit. Check the updated information.

Comment: Hello again @J2theC, Have you used first link you had provided ? Because, it is not working for me, I am still getting the Apple map.

Comment: You are getting apple maps with a tile overlay of google maps. If you look closer at the data inside the map, you can tell it's google maps. You cal also check that it's connecting to google maps api

Comment: We get the Google name at the bottom left side of the screen if its a Google map, right..? I am getting " legal ". Doesnt it mean its an Apple map ..?

Comment: Note that this is not a framework, but an static image. You can resize the static image to include the google maps brand inside the map.

Answer (score 0):

The website [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) works fine.

Comment: Thanks, But i dont want to show only the map, Routes, annotations are also required !

Answer (score 0):

You could now. Google present iOS SDK for iOS 6.  http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-new-way-to-add-google-maps-to-your.html